# Converting "html" type file into "io" type file in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html

Is there any way to convert `html` type file into an `io` type file?
For some reason here I need to initialize the file from html and I want to convert in io type file to display it in Image widget inform of `FileImage(_itemPic)`

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:io' as io;

Class AddNewItemView StatefulWidget{
..........
html.File _itemPic;
...........
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
               image: _itemPic != null
                     ? FileImage(_itemPic)  <<--- Now here I need io type file
                      : AssetImage(defaultItemimage),
               fit: BoxFit.cover,
             ),
            ),
          ),
..........
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible, the two objects don't share the same properties. Do you really need to use a `FileImage` ? I feel like you could use `MemoryImage` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a workaround. You can convert it to base64 first using the html reader. Then decode it into an IO File.

```
final reader = html.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataUrl(_itemPic);

reader.onLoad.first.then((res) {
  final encoded = reader.result as String;
  final imageBase64 = encoded.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'data:image/[^;]+;base64,'), '');// this is to remove some non necessary stuff
  io.File _itemPicIoFile = io.File.fromRawPath(base64Decode(base64Image));
});
```

Hope this helps! Regards

EDIT:
I missed the read part in the original post.