# FlutterFire Storage Put error : LOADING ERROR: Expected a value of type 'File', but got one of type 'File$'

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am developing a WebApp in Flutter and attempting to load a picked file from my computer to Firebase Storage. Using the FlutterFire Firebase Storage plugin and instructions.

There seems to be an issue with the file. Though all are defined as type File in my code. I receive the error above. And am not able to use the Put command. I am noticing also that there seems to be a problem between Dart.io File type and Dart.html File type. That is maybe causing this.

This is the first time I have tried this, and don't seem to be able to solve the issue, so would appreciate some help. Thanks so much.

Here is my upload code:

```
Future<void> _uploadMedia(File file) async {
_onLoading(true);
try {
  await fbs.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('uploads/file-to-upload.png')
      .putFile(file);
} catch (e) {
  // e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
}
```

And the code to select the file from the computer:

```
uploadMedia({required Function(File file) onSelected}) async {

var uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement()..accept = '*/*';
uploadInput.click();

uploadInput.onChange.listen(
  (changeEvent) {
    final file = uploadInput.files?.first;
    final reader = FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataUrl(file!);
  
    reader.onLoadEnd.listen(
   
    (loadEndEvent) async {
      onSelected(file);
    },
  );
 },
 );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take your idea and suggest a possible solution.

> I am noticing also that there seems to be a problem between Dart.io
> File type and Dart.html File type.

Try putting "as *name*;" at the end of the package import line and then using the word "io.YourType" when you need to declare something. Example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'my_library.dart' as myLib;

void main() {
  Stream stream = new Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]); // from async
  myLib.Stream myCustomStream = new myLib.Stream(); // from your library
}
```

Your situation: `io.File`

Comment: Hi @Legend5366. Thanks for your response. I have tried the solution recommended. However I now see that the code: reader.readAsDataUrl(file!); In the uploadMedia function above. Always returns the html File type. So I guess what I need it away to convert the Dart.Html File type to the Dart.io File type. Or a different way to upload the media from the computer.

Comment: I was looking for an answer to this question, maybe there is a solution, look at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933509/converting-html-type-file-into-io-type-file-in-flutter
But I'm still more inclined to think that you have the wrong code structure and I advise you to reconsider it. So, good luck on your code journey :)